# Getting ReSharper and VS 2015 CTP3 to play nice

Tags: resharper, visual-studio-2015

I've already asked on jetbrain's forum, to no avail, so I'll shoot here! :)

Have anyone got resharper and visual studio 2014 ctp 3 working together? I can't live without R#! :)

If you have, how have you done it?

Cheers,

Stian

Comment: There is probably no way. VS14 will be supported in ReSharper 9, and there's no EAP of that yet. I guess you'll just have to wait, together with the rest of us :)

Comment: +1 @IgalTabachnik Cheers, I was suspecting it :( Well.. only ctp, so no need to migrate, though I'm keen to check out all the new features of the language(s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no plans to support VS14 with the 8.x releases (mostly because it's a CTP, and requires changes for each release, which would mean multiple releases of a compatible 8.x, which then slows us down while we're also trying to work on ReSharper 9, and also due to architectural changes in ReSharper 9 that make back porting harder). As Igal mentions, support will be there with ReSharper 9. EAPs are coming fairly soon, but there's still going to be a little wait until they're ready to start (e.g. an installer would be nice!)

Comment: Thanks for the info, looks like I'm going to wait around for w9, 2k14 and R#9.x to be done before starting using 2k14 ;)